# T-SQL Query Gives Different Results when declaring integer vs calculating in-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

So I've been experimenting with some SQL random number generation in a query, and I noticed something odd.

Let's say I run the following query:

```
declare @Random int = CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1;

select CHOOSE(@Random,'One','Two','Three','Four','Five')
```

SQL random number gen is a little bulky, but the basic idea here is simple - pick a random number between 1 and 5, then display that number as text to the select window.  This works as expected.

However, if I take the SAME query, but paste the random number formula into the method instead of declaring it as an integer, so it's all on one line:

```
select CHOOSE(CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) +
    1,'One','Two','Three','Four','Five')
```

I still get values One to Five when I run the query, but sometimes I also get a NULL.  The NULL comes up pretty often, about one in 5 times.  If I put both queries into ssms and run them next to each other a few times, I often see a null value for the second query, but the first is never NULL.

So why is that?  Aren't these exactly the same calculation?  I have no idea why these two queries would give different results, but I feel like I can learn something useful about T-SQL by finding out.

Any experts want to enlighten me?

Comment: [See the section entitled "Expressions can be evaluated more than once."](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very subtle problem with the `choose` function in SQL Server (well, Microsoft probably considers it a feature).  The function is really shorthand for a `case` expression.  So, your expression:

```
select CHOOSE(CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) +
1,'One','Two','Three','Four','Five')
```

is translated into:

```
select (case when CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 = 1 then 'One'
             when CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 = 2 then 'Two'
             when CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 = 3 then 'Three'
             when CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 = 4 then 'Four'
             when CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5 as INT) + 1 = 5 then 'Five'
        end)
```

That means that the `newid()` is being called multiple times.  This is usually not the behavior that you want.

Comment: Yeah I am a stickler for semantics, sorry. With case in particular, much of the misunderstanding of how it works is precisely because people think of it as a statement.

Comment: Getting off topic now, but what is a 'statement'? I would have assumed that an expression is also a statement, though not a complete query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . It is more complicated than that.  It is a control flow statement for the scripting languages for Oracle and Postgres (as well as being an expression). There is ample scope for confusion.